# Convert between cv::mat and Qimage would make the program crash

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"    

#include <QtGui>

//make QImage point to the contents of cv::Mat
inline QImage const mat_to_qimage_ref(cv::Mat &mat)
{
  return QImage((unsigned char*)(mat.data), mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step1(), QImage::Format_RGB32);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QImage img("lena2.jpg");
  cv::Mat mat(img.height(), img.width(), CV_8UC4, img.bits(), img.bytesPerLine());
  QImage img = mat_to_qimage_ref(mat); //#1
  //QImage img2((unsigned char*)(mat.data), mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step, QImage::Format_RGB32); #2

  QLabel label;
  label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img)); //crash at here
  label.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

(#2) is ok, but #1 will occur undefined behavior?(my case is crash)

Besides, if you use it as the codes below, It is okay

```
 cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lena2.jpg");
 QLabel label;
 label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(mat_to_qimage_ref(img)));
 label.show();
```

Don't know what is happening, something related to cycle dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function should be like this:

```
    QImage mat_to_qimage_ref(const cv::Mat3b &src) {
        QImage dest(src.cols, src.rows, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; ++y) {
                const cv::Vec3b *srcrow = src[y];
                QRgb *destrow = (QRgb*)dest.scanLine(y);
                for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; ++x) {
                        destrow[x] = qRgba(srcrow[x][2], srcrow[x][1], srcrow[x][0], 255);
                }
        }
        return dest;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this looks like copy, but I want the Qimage point to the reference of cv::mat, since QLabel would copy the image or keep it untouch, I thought this should be save.Besides, I copy the cv::mat to QImage like this. memcpy(image.scanLine(i), mat.ptr(i), image.bytesPerLine() );

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to copy the image data, but just create a new QImage header for your data, try this:

```
Mat mat = Mat(...);

QImage qImage = QImage(
    (const uchar*)(mat.data),
    mat.cols,
    mat.rows,
    mat.step1(),
    QImage::Format_ARGB32); // if you have no alpha channel (CV_8UC3),
                            // you can use Format_RGB888
```

Also note, that OpenCV normally uses BGR channel order, you can use [rgbSwapped()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qimage.html#rgbSwapped) to solve this problem, but I don't know whether data gets copied with this function call.

Comment: I tried this solution(#2 of my codes), I wrapped it by function because I don't want to mess up with different format when converting between QImage and cv::mat everytimes. The function works well in simple case, but sometimes it will crash, just like the example I show.

Comment: Oh sorry, I overread that line. But if this works, why don't you just put it in your mat_to_qimage_ref function? I don't think it is possible to find a generic solution for all image formats. You'll have to switch over mat.type() or something similar to determine which QImage::Format you have to use.

Comment: I do think it is impossible to find a generic solution for all image formats, so I wrap the chores like these http://pastebin.com/MqQK6st0. Copy part works, but reference part would crash in some cases

Comment: I edit my post, alter the contents of the function(because I copy and paste the codes of transforming qimage to cv::mat but not cv::mat to qimage), still crash.I wonder why

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? The code you posted should not compile, as the "format" variable in mat_to_qimage_ref is not defined. Try calling the QImage constructor with the parameters I posted above (with mat.step1() and QImage::Format_ARGB32). If this works, expand your function by including a switch or multiple if-selections over mat.type(), just like it has been done in the link you posted before.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my post already ,because I copy the wrong piece of codes.I try your solution and wrapped it by function just like my first post(already edited, I use step but not step1 before), can't work either